# SSL Handshake Failing With 'Certificate Unknown'

Tags: tls, openssl, session-management

We have an application that is currently running via Http protocol. We are aiming at migrating it to Https. We have made the necessary changes and then during login to the application, I am getting a 'peer not authenticated' error message.

I am completely new to SSL world and so I google up and have captured the wireshark trace and the communication is looking as below:

> 1) Client sends [SYN] to server.
>   2) Server sends [SYN,ACK] to client.
>   3) Client sends [ACK] to server.
>   4) Client sends the message “Client
>   Hello” to the server.
>   5) Server sends its public key with the message
>   “Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done”
>   6) Alert 61, Level
>   Fatal, Description: Certificate Unknown // Failing here.

Request you to share your inputs on what could be going wrong. We are stuck here and not able to proceed further.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: What certificate are you using from what certificate authority? Is it valid in date, server name (common name) etc.?

Comment: I have received a Pc7b format certificate. It has 3 certificates in it, which I believe are root, intermediate and site level. I see that the server name / common name is as expected along with its validity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was [cross-posted to stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510308/ssl-handshake-failing-with-certificate-unknown).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a bundle that "includes the root certificate," that seems you're using a self-signed certificate, which is (by default and by design, untrusted).

You have a couple of options:

1. Install the root certificate of your self signed certs into the trusted root store of the workstations that will use this. (Not really recommended because it's clunky, but it will work).
2. Get an actual certificate from a certificate authority.